# CSV file to Varible struggling, using papa.parse

Tags: javascript, csv, papaparse

Ok, the goal is to copy the CSV from a file and store them as a string in javascript.

Using Papaparse I have managed to get the contents from the CSV file but I cant seem to save the string outside of papaparse to use in another script.

I have very new to javascript so be kind :)

the while loop is to adjust the format to how i need it, however if i can get the data out i can do this outside of where it currently sits. Any help is welcome as this is driving me nuts! many thanks!! :D

```
<title>Test stuff</title>
<script src="./Plugins/papaparse.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
Papa.parse("http://test_server/OpenSiteVisitTickets.csv", {
download: true,
complete: function(results) {
console.log("Remote file parsed!", results);
    var i= 0, x= [1],cname= [1],postc= [5],alenth = results.data.length -2;
        locations= [];
        while ( i < alenth )
            {
            var ltemp =[];

            ltemp = "[" + results.data[x] [cname] +", "+results.data[x] [postc] +"] ";
                locations = locations.concat(ltemp);
            i++,x++;
            }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = locations;
     }
    });
 </script>
 <script>
  // other script goes here and picks up locations var todo its funky shiz :)
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get the data out"?

Comment: I need to save it as a string for another bit of script to use, however if i try i get nothing. as i understand it locations should be a global varible but doesnt seem to work (or i more likely i have done something wrong :)

Comment: Well parsing a file over the network is asynchronous so any results you get won't be available until after the complete function is executed. The "other script goes here" needs to wait until that complete callback is fired; or more likely, the complete callback has to invoke that code.

Comment: A cleaner way of creating a global variable is to use `window.locations = ...` or even better is to just write the `var locations;` at the top of the file and set it in the callback. @Matt is right that your probably suffering from async agony though!

Comment: ooo thank you, that defiantly gives me something to play with (i did try them ways of creating a global variable as well, nice to know which is the cleaner way thou :)  now I need to go find out how i get the 2nd bit to wait till the 1st bit is finished.

Comment: ok making progress.... however still struggling. I can print out the contents of locations to page while in papaparse but if i try to print them after it doesnt seem to of written them to the locations i declared at the start?? code below, am i missing something? :S
    var locations;
    function papa() {
    Papa.parse("http://testserver/OpenSiteVisitTickets.csv", {
 download: true,
 complete: function(results) {locations = results.data;
 }});} </script>
    </head>
    <body><p id="demo"></p>
    <script> papa();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = locations;
    </script>

Comment: @Seb: Look up asynchronous programming. The last line (the one that sets the innerHTML) executes before the download and parsing is complete. Even though you call `papa()` as the line before setting the innerHTML, the browser doesn't wait to finish downloading the page before continuing script execution. That would cause the page to lock up and be a bad experience. So you specify a callback function that gets executed when the operation is complete, but that happens out-of-line of normal execution. Make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Matt for your answer;
and thanks Nepeo for you advise on globals;

Well parsing a file over the network is asynchronous so any results you get won't be available until after the complete function is executed. The "other script goes here" needs to wait until that complete callback is fired; or more likely, the complete callback has to invoke that code. –  Matt 2 days ago

A cleaner way of creating a global variable is to use window.locations = ... or even better is to just write the var locations; at the top of the file and set it in the callback. @Matt is right that your probably suffering from async agony though! –  nepeo 2 days ago